# make users appear as horizontal list in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I enabled the `whosonline` module on my website, and users appear as a [vertical list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XNZi.jpg). How do I make users appear as a horizontal list?

Answer (score 0):

try to use CSS float:left; or display:inline-block;

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me more details ? Where's that css file ?

Comment: in browser (chrome, firefox, opera) right mouse click on element, then click "explore element", in bottom panel u can see all style for this element and css file where it is written. Change this file write .whosonline li {display: inline-block !important;} then refresh page. if not work clear casche. (sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Click with your right mouse button on ul list, and inspect classname of this list then apply this css code to it

```
.whosonline li {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: could you give link to your site?

Comment: I understand that I have to add that css code ... but honestly I dont understand when you say "Click with your right mouse button on ul list"... Where's ul list ? :(

Comment: you dont have to do it, just copy css code from my answer directly to your styles.

Comment: yes, if it wont work add an important rule to it `.whosonline li {display: inline-block !important;}` becouse you have got lot of CSS files and this plugin could overwrite it.

Comment: wowww it works :xxx thanks you so muchhh ^^ Can I ask you other question ? ^^

Comment: Im using J25 and S5 module register. Try to click Register button in contact page and register an account. You'll get this error : Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/s10s/public_html/modules/mod_s5_register/captcha/validate.php on line 21 . I got it whenever I try to register new account. I tried to disable captcha setting in Module mod_s5_register and Users Configuration  but it didnt work. How to solve this? ... :(